# Dice roll probability, at least 9 total?

Tags: probability, dice

If I have two dice with $6$ sides each, what is the probability of me rolling atleast $9$ total? I think I'm correct when thinking that the probability of rolling a $9$ is $\frac{4}{36}$, that is $11.1...\%$, but how do I go from here to calculate the "at least" part?

Comment: Hint: Make a $6\times 6$ table, and tick off the boxes that lead to a total of at least $9$.

Comment: Make, say, a $6 \times 6$ table and score those off that have a sum greater than or equal to $9$.

Comment: Checking your answer is easy with _Mathematica_: `Probability[x + y >= 9, 
 Distributed[{x, y}, DiscreteUniformDistribution[{{1, 6}, {1, 6}}]]]` gives $\frac{5}{18}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 &\overrightarrow{ D2} & \color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{2} & \color{blue}{3} & \color{blue}{4} & \color{blue}{5} & \color{blue}{6} \\ \hline D1\downarrow\\\hline
\color{blue}{1} &&2 &3 &4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\ \hline
 \color{blue}{2}&& 3 & 4&5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\ \hline
\color{blue}{3} &&4  &5 &6 & 7 & 8 & \color{red}{9}\\ \hline
\color{blue}{4} &&5 & 6 & 7 & 8 &\color{red}{9} &\color{red}{10}\\ \hline
\color{blue}{5} &&6 &7 &8 &\color{red}{9} &\color{red}{10} &\color{red}{11} \\ \hline
\color{blue}{6} && 7 & 8 & \color{red}{9} &\color{red}{10} &\color{red}{11}&\color{red}{12}\\\hline
\end{array}$

Every cell containing a number in red, satisfies: $(D1+D2) \ge 9$

Assuming that each die is a fair die, the probability of obtaining any number from 1-6 on each of the two dice is $\frac{1}{6}$.

For example, the probability of obtaining $(D1,D2)=(1,1)$ is $\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{1}{36}\right)$

Every individual outcome in the table is obtained with probability $\frac{1}{36}$ as each result is equally likely.

Since there are 36 (6 $\times$ 6 table) total outcomes, the probability will be $\frac{x}{36}$ or an equivalent fraction.

Try to find $x$ via a simple counting method (count how many numbers in red there are).

Comment: To use a counting method, it might help if you mentioned whether each result is equally likely.

Comment: use `\begin{array}{c|c|...}....\end{array}`, `\color{red}` and `{\bf r}`

Answer (score 2):

P(at least a sum of 9)
= P(9 <= the sum <= 12)
= P((3,6) or (4,5) or (5,4) or (6,3))
+ P((4,6) or (5,5) or (6,4))
+ P((5,6) or (6,5))
+ P((6,6))
= (4 + 3 + 2 + 1)/36
= 5/18

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Thanks. I certainly need some math symbols to present my ideas better.

Answer (score 2):

$$\newcommand{\c}[2]{{}^{#1}{\mathbb C}_{#2}}
(x+x^2+...+x^6)^2=x^2(x^6-1)^2(x-1)^{-2}=x^2(x^{12}-2x^6+1)\underbrace{(x-1)^{-2}}_{\displaystyle\sum (k+1)x^k}\\
=...-2\underbrace{(2+...+5)}_{14}+...+1\underbrace{(8+...11)}_{38}$$
.
$$P=\frac{10}{36}=\frac5{18}$$

Comment: This looks like an elegant answer and I'd like to understand it fully.  Have you used a probability generating function? I thought that $G(t)=\frac{1}{6}t+\frac{1}{6}t^2+\frac{1}{6}t^3+\frac{1}{6}t^4+\frac{1}{6}t^5+         \frac{1}{6}t^6$ for one die.  If so what happened to $\frac{1}{6}$? Was squaring for the two dice rolls? I'd ask this as a question but it seems logical to keep it here.  I'd be grateful of any thoughts you have.

Comment: @Karl you can take $1/6$ common from both hence you need to divide by 36 now or then.

Answer (score 1):

A rough and simpleton, but correct, answer: If you have two dices, the total of possibilites are 36, according the Five σ's table. The total of valid results are 10, so the ratio is 10/36 or 5/18.

Answer (score 0):

3+6=9

4+5=9

5+4=9

6+3=9

4+6=10

5+5=10

6+4=10

5+6=11

6+5=11

6+6=12

10 of 36 of the total values are shown here 9-12, so the probability is 5/18 ($0.2$$\overline7$).